# Could not find error location when pushing to org

Tags: error, scratch-org

I recently pulled data from my bitbucket and tried pushing to scratch org, and i am getting an error like this.

**sfdx force:source:push -u TestScratchOrg**

**PROJECT PATH**     ----------        ***ERROR***

**N/A**       ---------------------       **Entity 'default' not found. (3:22)**

I have created 5-6 objects but i don't know in which file this issue is occuring.

Any help on this??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have mis-configuration in the sfdx-project.json file. In this file you need to define the Path and the default path. More information https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

For defining default you can set additional parameter:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app"
    },
    {
      "path": "test-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "41.0"
}
```